# Extract Multiple data from excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, text-extraction, import-from-excel

I have an excel cell data and it contains various tag multiple times.
I want to extract the specific texts in various columns

```
<ns0:PRODUCT xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns0="http://www.tibco.com/schemas/Elink_CalculatePricing/ProjectResource/Schema/InterfaceXSD/Schema.xsd3" PRODUCT_CD="32864">     <ns0:PRESCRIPTIONDETAILS>         <ns0:PRESCRIPTIONDETAIL NAME="PRISM" VALUE="0"/>         <ns0:PRESCRIPTIONDETAIL NAME="FRAME" VALUE="54"/>     </ns0:PRESCRIPTIONDETAILS>     <ns0:LENS COLOR_CD="TSG" COLOR_CHANGED_FROM="" LN_MATL_TYPE_CD="TR " LN_STYLE_CD="SV    " LN_TYPE_CD="NA ">         <ns0:CATEGORY NAME="SingleVision">             <ns0:CATEGORYGROUP NAME="Base Lenses" PRICE="12.48"/>         </ns0:CATEGORY>         <ns0:CATEGORY NAME="Plastic">             <ns0:CATEGORYGROUP NAME="Photochromics - SV" PRICE="38.00"/>         </ns0:CATEGORY>         <ns0:CATEGORY NAME="ADD-ONs">             <ns0:CATEGORYGROUP NAME="CZL AVANCE UV" PRICE="46.64" TYPE="Service"/>             <ns0:CATEGORYGROUP NAME="CZL_UV" PRICE="38" TYPE="Service"/>             <ns0:CATEGORYGROUP NAME="HANDLING-SHIPPING" PRICE="1.9" TYPE="Lens"/>         </ns0:CATEGORY>     </ns0:LENS> </ns0:PRODUCT>
```

here i have price multiple times.
I want to take out the price for each time into a separate column in excel.
Is this possible

Answer (score 0):

I've assumed that what you listed above is listed in cell A2.

- In Cell B1 Enter (use quotes): "Base Lenses" PRICE
- In Cell C1 Enter (use quotes): "Photochromics - SV" PRICE
- In Cell D1 Enter (use quotes): "CZL AVANCE UV" PRICE
- In Cell E1 Enter (use quotes): "CZL_UV" PRICE
- In Cell F1 Enter (use quotes): "HANDLING-SHIPPING" PRICE

**Now for the formulas**

In Cell B2 Enter the following formula

```
=VALUE(LEFT(MID($A2,FIND(B$1,$A2)+LEN(B$1)+2,10),FIND("""",MID($A2,FIND(B$1,$A2)+LEN(B$1)+2,10))-1))
```

then you can drag this formula to the right, and down for as many cells as you need.